# Average value of all monotonously decreasing functions $f_n(x) \in [0,1]$ on the interval $x \in [0,1]$

Tags: analysis

I just wondered if it is possible to derive the average value of all monotonously decreasing functions $f_n(x) \in [0,1]$ on the interval $x \in [0,1]$.

Or to put it another way: Given a monotonously decreasing functions for which applies $0 \leq f(x) \leq 1$ and $x \in [0,1]$ what is $\bar{f}$?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You seem to be asking about a sequence of functions. The $1/n$ outside the summation is meaningless.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that there are only countably many such functions, but this isn't so.